# Google Apps Script Copying certain cells from a sheet into another sheet without repeating data

Tags: google-apps-script

The code below is working well for me in terms of using a trigger word "Cancelled" in locating rows that have been labelled cancelled by the user in the spreadsheet utilizing this to get the values of 2 cells from the row and is copied into a separate sheet.

```
function moveToCancelled() {
  var triggerCancel = "Cancelled";
  var hospitalSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SPMC OVP-DOH MAIPP");
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cancelled Requests");
  var values = hospitalSheet.getRange(2, 18, hospitalSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  Logger.log(daysUntilEnd);

  for (var i = 0; i < (hospitalSheet.getLastRow()); i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == triggerCancel ) {
      var targetLocation = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      var targetSheetRange = hospitalSheet.getRange(i + 2, 6);
      var targetLocation1 = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow() + 1, 2);
      var targetSheetRange1 = hospitalSheet.getRange(i + 2, 13);

      targetSheetRange.copyTo(targetLocation);
      targetSheetRange1.copyTo(targetLocation1);
    }    
  }
}
```

My problem is that I would like to avoid replicating data copied into the new sheet. What can I try next? I just got back coding using Apps Script and would like to see the possibilities in doing this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about using the value of "Cancelled" as follows?

In this sample, after the row was copied, the value of "Cancelled" is changed to "Cancelled_copied". By this, when the script is run again, only the rows with "Cancelled" are copied. By this, I thought that your goal might be able to be achieved.

And, in your script, `copyTo` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function moveToCancelled() {
  var triggerCancel = "Cancelled";
  var newTriggerCancel = triggerCancel + "_copied";

  var hospitalSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SPMC OVP-DOH MAIPP");
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cancelled Requests");
  var values = hospitalSheet.getRange(2, 1, hospitalSheet.getLastRow(), 18).getValues();
  var { v, cells } = values.reduce((o, r, i) => {
    if (r[17] == triggerCancel) {
      o.v.push([r[5], r[12]]);
      o.cells.push(`R${i + 2}`);
    }
    return o;
  }, { v: [], cells: [] });
  if (v.length == 0) return;
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v);
  hospitalSheet.getRangeList(cells).setValue(newTriggerCancel);
}
```

When this script is run, when the column "R" is "Cancelled", the values of columns "F" and "M" are put into the target sheet. And, "Cancelled" is changed to "Cancelled_copied". By this, when the script is run again, the copied row is skipped.

#### Note:

- In this modification, your goal is achieved by changing the value of "Cancelled" to "Cancelled_copied". This is a sample modification. So, for example, I think that you can put "copied" in a new column and you can use it for checking. In this case, please modify the above script.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))

Comment: Super helpful and informative. Thank you so much for your time! It works like a charm. and yes I do agree the copyTo used in a loop is very process costly and takes a lot of runtime to do. The following references you have given me has helped me understand more tools I can use in the future. Cheers!